# Get Time stamp using Java GMT+5:30

Tags: java, date, datetime, time, timestamp

I want Timestamp of given date.
using this code

```
 public static String getTimestamp(String time)
        {
            DateFormat dfm = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss");  

            long unixtime = 0;
            dfm.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5:30"));
        try
        {
            unixtime = dfm.parse(time).getTime();  
            unixtime=unixtime/1000;
        } 
        catch (ParseException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ""+unixtime;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            System.out.println(getTimestamp("11-05-15 11:54:55"));
        }
```

but when i enter this date `11-05-15 11:54:55` then program return me 1420957495 this timestamp which is timestamp of Jan (01) but i want May(06)
please help me

Comment: Try commenting out the line `unixtime=unixtime/1000;`

Comment: Same Output coming after comment the line 
it is GMT+5:30 Indian Time Zone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this
DateFormat dfm = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy hh:mm:ss");

Upper case MM is for month and lower case is for minute

Answer (score 2):

## Your Offset Is Invalid

A valid offset must include **padded zero**. Your offset string `GMT+5:30` should be `GMT+05:30` with a `0` before the `5`.

Beyond that, [the Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30164476/642706) by [Meno Hochschild](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2491410/meno-hochschild) is correct and wise.

## java.time

The java.util.Date/.Calendar and SimpleDateFormat classes are notoriously troublesome, confusing, and flawed. **Avoid them.**

Instead use [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package found in Java 8 and later. Where lacking, use the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library.

Here is some java.time code (Java 8).

First, parse your input into a "local" date-time value, meaning without any time zone attached. As there was no offset nor time zone included with the input, this value could apply to any particular locality.

```
String input = "11-05-15 11:54:55";  // Strongly recommend using 4-digit year whenever possible, as suggested in Meno Hochschild’s Answer.
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss" ); // No need for Locale in this case, but always consider it.
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse( input , formatter );
```

Next, we are *presuming* this value was meant to represent a moment in India. Let’s assign a time zone. We could assign merely an offset. But generally we should use a time zone. A time zone is an offset *plus* the past, present, and future set of rules for adjustments and anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time.

First we instantiate a time zone for India. Then we generate a `ZonedDateTime` based on the `LocalDateTime` while adding a time zone.

```
// Assign a time zone.
//ZoneId zoneId_plus_5_30 = ZoneId.of( "GMT+05:30" );  // You can use an offset, but know that a time zone is *more* than an offset.
ZoneId zoneIdKolkata = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" );  // Better to use a time zone name if one is applicable. Ex: "Asia/Kolkata".
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTimeKolkata = ZonedDateTime.of( localDateTime , zoneIdKolkata );
```

For fun, let’s adjust the same moment to UTC and to Montréal.

```
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTimeUtc = zonedDateTimeKolkata.withZoneSameInstant( ZoneOffset.UTC );
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTimeMontréal = zonedDateTimeKolkata.withZoneSameInstant( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "Input: " + input );
System.out.println( "localDateTime: " + localDateTime );
System.out.println( "zonedDateTimeKolkata: " + zonedDateTimeKolkata );
System.out.println( "zonedDateTimeUtc: " + zonedDateTimeUtc );
System.out.println( "zonedDateTimeMontréal: " + zonedDateTimeMontréal );
```

When run.

```
Input: 11-05-15 11:54:55
localDateTime: 2015-05-11T11:54:55
zonedDateTimeKolkata: 2015-05-11T11:54:55+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]
zonedDateTimeUtc: 2015-05-11T06:24:55Z
zonedDateTimeMontréal: 2015-05-11T02:24:55-04:00[America/Montreal]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change your pattern. So far the accepted answer is right with respect to month. What is still missing is the pattern symbol for the hour of day. It should be H instead of h. Or if you prefer the English hour notation, you can use an additional letter "a" indicating AM/PM. So the final solution is:

```
DateFormat dfm = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss");
```

or

```
DateFormat dfm = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

And I recommend to use 4-digit-years to exclude any ambivalence using yyyy, by the way.